# SurfaceView inside TableLayout

Tags: android, surfaceview, tablelayout

I am trying to create an application in android, with main activity which has table layout as,

1st Row: 1 image (which will take upto 85% of screen space)

2nd Row: 3 images (which will take upto 10% of screen space)

3rd Row: 1 surfaceView (which will take upto 5% of screen space)

Code: MainLayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


 <TableLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/white"

        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"

        >
 <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.85"
    android:gravity="top|center"
     >  


  <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/icamera"
  android:scaleType="fitXY" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:src="@drawable/cam_off"
  android:layout_column="0"
  android:layout_span="3"
  android:layout_gravity="center|top" 
  android:paddingTop="0sp"
  android:paddingRight="0sp"
  android:paddingLeft="0sp"
  android:paddingBottom="0sp"
  />


</TableRow> 

 <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.10"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
     >      
   <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/isetting"
  android:scaleType="centerInside"  
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="0dp" 
  android:src="@drawable/settings"
  android:layout_column="0"
  android:layout_weight="0.30"
  android:layout_gravity="left|bottom" 

  android:paddingTop="0sp"
  android:paddingRight="0sp"
  android:paddingLeft="0sp"
  android:paddingBottom="0sp"
  />

  <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/icredits"
  android:scaleType="centerInside"  
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="0dp" 
  android:src="@drawable/credits"
  android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
  android:layout_column="1"
  android:layout_weight="0.30"

  android:paddingTop="0sp"
  android:paddingRight="0sp"
  android:paddingLeft="0sp"
  android:paddingBottom="0sp"
  />

  <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/ihelp"
  android:scaleType="centerInside"  
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="0dp" 
  android:src="@drawable/help"
  android:layout_column="2"
  android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
  android:paddingTop="0sp"
  android:paddingRight="0sp"
  android:paddingLeft="0sp"
  android:paddingBottom="0sp"
  android:layout_weight="0.30"
  /> 

 </TableRow>  

  <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.05"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
     > 

<SurfaceView 
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView2" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_column="0"
  android:layout_span="3"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
  android:background="@color/black"
  android:scaleType="fitXY" 
  android:paddingTop="0sp"
  android:paddingRight="0sp"
  android:paddingLeft="0sp"
  android:paddingBottom="0sp">
</SurfaceView>

 </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

but when I run the application image of 1st row gets disappear and it shows:

1st Row: 3 Images (which takes upto 10% of screen space)

2nd Row: Surface view (which takes upto 90% of screen space)

Kindly please help me out..

Comment: You are using layout weights nested in some of your image views, but not providing the associated 0dp within those imageviews.  So the three images might run into issues from that section of code at some point.  I haven't tried layout weights in rows.  If its supported then I don't see an immediate issue.

Comment: I have used layout weight in images of second row ( to divide raw in 3 equal width cells)which gets displayed without any issue. My problem is image of row 1 does not show up.

Comment: I undertand, but your current ImageView components won't use the weights properly without the 0dp instead of the wrap_content / match_parent attribute.

Comment: ok, I understood your point of concern and updated also in my code.

Comment: thanks for that. but at the same time can you please trace it out why surface view utilizes space of first row also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone for helping..
but I got workaround for this.

in onCreate method of activity i updated following code:

```
 public class MainScreenActivity extends Activity 
{
private static final String TAG = "Recorder";
public static SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
public static SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
public static Camera mCamera ;
public static boolean mPreviewRunning;
public static SharedPreferences sharedPref;
public static Display display;
public static  int swidth,sheight;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Requires import android.view.Window
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen_layout);




    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView2);
    mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();



            /*************added code*************/      
    display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
     int width = display.getWidth(); // ((display.getWidth()*20)/100)
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
     int height = display.getHeight();// ((display.getHeight()*30)/100)

    swidth = width;// width*10/100;
    sheight = height*5/100;//height*15/100;
    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(swidth,sheight);
    lp.span=3;
    lp.column=0;
    lp.weight=0.05f;
    mSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            /*************added code*************/
           . . . .
      }
    .  . . . 
  }
```